# Can I legally drive through the backstreets in Seattle?

Tags: usa, legal, driving, seattle

Assume that:

1. I have a valid US driver's license and have the other elements to legally drive on a normal street in the US.
2. I'd like drive through a backstreet in Seattle but I'm not doing so to access some garage or other location that requires going through the backstreet.
3. The backstreet doesn't seem to have any sign against driving.
4. The backstreet connects two normal streets.

Can I legally drive through the backstreets in Seattle?

---

Example of backstreet in Seattle:

[image]

There exist many such backstreets in Seattle downtown.

Comment: That looks like an alley. Does it have a name? Does it connect two streets, or only lead to a garage door?

Comment: @KateGregory connect two streets, idk about name. There are many such backstreets in Seattle.

Comment: Google Maps says this is "Nord Alley." A Google Search on "Nord Alley" returns documents showing the City of Seattle recently doing work to improve it. Trash and recycling trucks use the alley to collect, so it's passable by (big) vehicles. Seattle Municipal Code Sec. 11.14.025 defines "Alley" as "'Alley' means a highway not designed for general travel and primarily used as a means of access to the rear of residences and business establishments." It's the same definition as found in the Washington State Statutes.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica thanks, can I legally drive through it?

Comment: I didn't post as an answer, because I'm not facile with Washington law. But I think you can. Perhaps this'll do: I wouldn't hesitate to drive down Nord Alley, as the city's and the state's definition of "alley" calls it a "highway" and leaves room for non-general travel.

Comment: Yes you can:  https://www.seattletimes.com/seattle-news/transportation/one-way-to-sidestep-seattle-traffic-cut-through-an-alley/  You might get temporarily stuck by fairly unsympathetic slow commercial traffic though and if you get into an accident you might find yourself in an uphill battle to try to argue any innocence.

Comment: @lamont, that looks like an answer, please post it as such.

Comment: While most people might not cavalierly walk down the middle of a main street, they probably regard a back alley as a low traffic area where pedestrians aren't so constrained.  So if you drive through a back alley, be even more cautious than you normally would about pedestrians, cyclists, small children, etc.

Comment: Thank you all for the great comments!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll summarize below the answers received in the comment section.

> Can I legally drive through the backstreets in Seattle?

Yes. From [this article](https://www.seattletimes.com/seattle-news/transportation/one-way-to-sidestep-seattle-traffic-cut-through-an-alley/):

1. The speed limit is 15 MPH.
2. It's typically referred to as an *alley*.
3. One has to be extra careful about pedestrians as they may not watch for cars coming from the alleys.
4. Cars must yield to pedestrians. "When emerging from an alley, drivers are supposed to yield the right of way to any pedestrian, bicyclist or car when entering into the adjacent roadway. In Bellevue, any vehicle exiting an alley must first stop and yield to pedestrians, bicyclists and all other vehicles." (-> notice that the law depends on the city).
5. Directions: "The alleys allow for two-way travel, unless they are marked with “One Way” or “Do Not Enter” sign".
6. Regarding parking: "City code prohibits anyone from stopping, standing or parking a vehicle within an alley in a way that would block access to adjacent property. There is no set limit of time for how long you can park in an alley, but only commercial vehicles with a permit may park there, Westing said."

---

Comments:

> - Yes you can: [seattletimes.com/seattle-news/transportation/…](https://www.seattletimes.com/seattle-news/transportation/one-way-to-sidestep-seattle-traffic-cut-through-an-alley/) You might get temporarily stuck by fairly unsympathetic slow commercial traffic though and if you get into an accident you might find yourself in an uphill battle to try to argue any innocence. [lamont](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/122822/lamont) [2 days ago](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/168550/can-i-legally-drive-through-the-backstreets-in-seattle#comment420094_168550)
> - Google Maps says this is "Nord Alley." A Google Search on "Nord Alley" returns documents showing the City of Seattle recently doing work to improve it. Trash and recycling trucks use the alley to collect, so it's passable by (big) vehicles. Seattle Municipal Code Sec. 11.14.025 defines "Alley" as "'Alley' means a highway not designed for general travel and primarily used as a means of access to the rear of residences and business establishments." It's the same definition as found in the Washington State Statutes. [DavidSupportsMonica](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/76708/davidsupportsmonica) [2 days ago](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/168550/can-i-legally-drive-through-the-backstreets-in-seattle#comment420086_168550)
> - While most people might not cavalierly walk down the middle of a main street, they probably regard a back alley as a low traffic area where pedestrians aren't so constrained. So if you drive through a back alley, be even more cautious than you normally would about pedestrians, cyclists, small children, etc. [Kyralessa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/2618/kyralessa) [2 days ago](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/168550/can-i-legally-drive-through-the-backstreets-in-seattle/168586#comment420102_168550)